# android: app version to Google Play

Tags: android, version, apk

I have already published an app to version 2, and have uploaded an app with version 3 to to Google Play as a beta testing version, and then discovered with errors, so I have modified the codes is now ready for publish.

I tried to upload the correct apk with version 3 to Google Play, but it says I have already uploaded a version 3 apk already.

### Question:

How to remove the wrong apk from the Google Play? Or what should I do? Or I can only modify and upload the app as version 4?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can not remove the apk from google play. You just have now update your application version and upload the new apk on google play that is the only way.

Comment: yes yes...it seems so...i have pressed everything in the google play and seem all things cannot be deleted after upload...could you please give it as an answer? =)

Comment: First of all, you do not publish a beta version. By definition, beta testing occurs before publishing. Once you publish it, it's not beta anymore. That said, it's pretty common that the very act of publishing to a wider audience reveals unexpected bugs. Then you correct those bugs and increase a minor portion of the version number, i.e., call your new version 3.0.1, for example.

Comment: actually i would like to ask what is the difference between version code and version name? both of them need to be integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not remove the apk from google play. You just have now update your application version and upload the new apk on google play that is the only way.

Please note that package names for app files are unique and permanent, so please choose wisely. Package names cannot be deleted or re-used in the future. Keep in mind that if you've lost your keystore, you'll have to publish the app with a new package name and a new key. You should also update the description of the original app and unpublish it.

If the app was ever published, this will not work. You can unpublish an app, but you cannot delete any .apk files that were ever active while the app was published. (This behavior is undocumented as far as I can find.) This is unfortunate; it would be nice to be able to completely remove all traces of an app that was never downloaded by anyone. Even better would be a sandbox area that emulated all aspects of Google Play, including buying your own app (and would support doing it through the emulator).

Check out [HERE](http://www.cynosurex.com/Forums/DisplayComments.php?file=Java/Android/Tips_and_Tricks_for_Uploading_Apps_to_Google_Market)